# projections and column space

Tags: linear-algebra

If $A^2=A$, is a projection and $v_1$ and $v_2$ make up the column space (basis) of the span why does $Av=v$? Why does multiplying $A$ times a column space vector not change the column space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every vector $\vec v$ in the column space of $A$ can be written in the form $\vec v = A\vec u$. Then
$$A\vec v = A(A\vec u) = (A^2)\vec u = (A)\vec u = \vec v.$$